# Excel report from TFS for all testing effort including exploratory testing sessions

Tags: testing, reporting-services, tfs, analysis, exploratory

We are currently producing weekly reports on test team performance using `Excel` via the `Cube` and these have worked well up to now.  We report on weekly testing statistics for test cases executed and their outcome, bugs raised and work items updated, etc.

With the introduction of `exploratory testing` during this sprint of testing any exploratory sessions performed are not included in the testing statistics, and the pivot table field list does not seem to include any options for the exploratory sessions.

Could someone please help identify if this is possible?

After a Google search I was only able to locate details of how to run exploratory test sessions and how to view testing results from the Test Plan in Test Manager 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered on the following thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1b2b0ae-a586-41da-9867-2ccf6b1e9e92/excel-cube-report-for-all-testing-effort-including-exploratory-testing-sessions

Reporting on exploratory testing is not currently possible - a feature request has been submitted to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4358646-include-exploratory-test-sessions-in-the-tfs-wareh